# Replicate ASP.NET Control/Functionality over pages with a single control

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I got multiple pages (not all) with the same functionality (a control for send Contact info) even for Dekstop and Mobile websites.

I want to create just one control and declare it as something like: "`<asp:MySendInfo />`" wherever I want to display all the TextBoxes, Lables, load events, etc, etc; that compose the hole functionality.

I can't use iframes or a masterpage.

Comment: Look up "User Controls" for ASP.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a comment from Yuriy above says, you are looking for [User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y6wb1a0e(v=vs.100).aspx) (they usually have an .ascx extension). They work pretty much the same as ASP.NET Pages (.aspx).
For a quick start [this is how you add them to your project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wt3k2fyw(v=vs.100).aspx) and [how you register and call them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/sbz9etab(v=vs.100).aspx) in your page.